# RecyclewView duplica el item que he modificado

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragment, recyclerview

Tengo dos fragments, uno con un recyclerview que contiene una lista de items, cuando clicko a uno de estos items se me abre otro fragment con datos de ese item, los cuales puedo modificar, el problema esta en que cuando modifico algo de ese item y vuelvo al fragment que contiene la lista de todos los items, este item modificado aparece duplicado, uno con los datos de antes y otro con los modificados.
Esto suele ocurrirme la segunda vez que modifico un mismo item, asi que intuyo que el problema viene en que no se actualiza correctamente las posiciones de la lista del recycler con las que obtiene de la base de datos (Firestore). También tengo el mismo problema al añadir un objeto nuevo a la lista.

Este es el codigo de la creacion de la lista:

```
tocinosRef.orderBy("estado")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.w("TAG", "listen:error", e);
                            return;
                        }
                        for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            switch (dc.getType()) {
                                case ADDED:
                                    final Cerda cerda = new Cerda();
                                    cerda.setNumeroRegistro(Integer.parseInt(dc.getDocument().getData().get("numeroRegistro").toString()));
                                    cerda.setEstado(dc.getDocument().getData().get("estado").toString());
                                    cerda.setId(dc.getDocument().getId());
                                    listCerdas.add(cerda);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    break;
                                case MODIFIED:
                                    final Cerda cerda2 = new Cerda();
                                    cerda2.setNumeroRegistro(Integer.parseInt(dc.getDocument().getData().get("numeroRegistro").toString()));
                                    cerda2.setEstado(dc.getDocument().getData().get("estado").toString());
                                    cerda2.setId(dc.getDocument().getId());
                                    listCerdas.set(dc.getOldIndex(), cerda2);
                                    adapter.notifyItemChanged(dc.getOldIndex());
                                    break;
                                case REMOVED:
                                    Log.d("TAG", "Removed Msg: " + dc.getDocument().toObject(Message.class));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

        recycler = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.recyclerId);
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        adapter = new AdapterCerdas(listCerdas);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: En el código solo se ve que cada vez añades elementos a `listCerdas`, y es por ese motivo por el que se duplican. ¿Cuál es el código con el que modificas los elementos? ¿Cuál es la lógica que estás poniendo en práctica? Sin entender eso veo difícil encontrar una solución a tu problema.

Comment: Al entrar en la aplicacion se listan todos los elementos encontrados en la bd, por eso la adicion de elementos a listCerdas en el case: ADD. El codigo de modificacion, ubicado en otro fragment, lo que hace es cambiar el estado de un elemento, por lo que al volver a este fragment capta que hay una modificacion de uno de los documentos y entra en el case: MODIFIED. Alli cargo en un nuevo objeto todos sus atributos, incluidos el nuevo estado establecido, y trato de sustituir en la lista este nuevo objeto por el que ha sido modificado, pero en esta parte es en la que falla.

Comment: En lugar de sustituirlo lo que hace es crearme otro similar pero con el estado cambiado (que es lo que he modificado). Esto suele fallarme la segunda vez que hago una modificacion a un item, por eso creo que las posiciones de los items en la bd (dc.getOldIndex) se descuadran con lo de listCerdas.

Comment: Todo eso debiste explicarlo en la pregunta. Cuando toque modificar no tienes por qué crear otro objeto, deberías recuperar la referencia del item y cambiar lo que haya que cambiar. El problema es que estás entendiendo una actualización como una re-creación, lo cual no es correcto.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, tras pensarlo mejor he recogido el objeto de la lista y lo he modificado con los nuevos valores y ya no me da ningún problema de duplicidad. Gracias por tu ayuda!